# Java exceptions when trying to modify ArrayList

Tags: android

I'm working on an Android game which fires an `onDraw()` method 30 times per second.

In this method I am iterating through an `ArrayList` of objects and drawing them with an `object.Draw()` method I created.

My problem is, I want to add objects to this `ArrayList` in the game's `onTouchEvent()`, but I sometimes get the following error:

`java.util.ConcurrentModificationException`

I know what's happening here, the `onTouchEvent()` fires when I touch the screen, so objects are being added to my `ArrayList`, but sometimes this happens as my `onDraw()` method is firing, which iterates through my `ArrayList`, and this causes the exception. Makes sense.

My question is, how can I add objects to my `ArrayList` when I touch the screen if it's being iterated through in my `onDraw()` method? Can I try to detect touch events in my `onDraw()` method? This way there will never be a problem. This is my first time programming games for Android, how is this kind of thing usually handled?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're accessing and modifying the list from different threads. Try [synchronizing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html) access to the list (so only one thread will have access to it at a time).

Another option might be to use [CopyOnWriteArrayList](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html).